# limit of perturbed rank deficient matrix as perturbation goes to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits, statistics

Given a $p \times p$ matrix $X^TX$  such that rank$(X^TX) = r<p$. How can I evaluate the following limit:
$$
\lim_{\lambda \to 0} (X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}.
$$

Comment: How can you guarantee the inverse matrix $(X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}$ exist if $rank(X^T X) < p$?

Comment: @xzm it always exists since its smallest eigenvalue will be $\lambda.$ The standard method for dealing with question like this is to use the eigendecomposition of $XX^T$, which is all nice and real since $XX^T$ is symmetric. That is, if $A$ is symmetric and $A = Q\Lambda Q^T,$ then you can find a simple formula for $(A+\lambda I)^{-1}.$ 

Filling out the details would be a good exercise.

Comment: I think it's psuedo inverse of X. If hen X is a full rank (fat) matrix, then it is X^T(XX^T)^{-1}. I can provide a proof if you want.

Comment: @SungheeYun I was hoping it would converge to $(X^TX)^\dagger$ as you say, but since the pseudo inverse is not a continuous function the proof isn't straight forward. I guess I need to do it by eigen-decomposition as mentioned in a previous comment

Comment: I suggest you consider the case of $p=1$ and $r=0$.  As written the limit does not exist.  I think you forgot to write $\lambda \gt 0$ and you want the limit from the right only, in which case the limit is $+\infty$.  Next step: consider the case when $X^T X$ is diagonal for general $p$.

Comment: @dezdichado If we take $X^TX = Q \Gamma Q$ then $(X^T X +\lambda I)^{-1} = Q \text{diag}( (\gamma_1 + \lambda)^{-1}, \dots, (\gamma_r + \lambda)^{-1}, \lambda^{-1},\dots, \lambda^{-1} ) Q^T $ right? So taking the limit $\lambda \to 0^+$ doesn't work here? I'm not sure how to show that this converges to $(X^TX)^\dagger$

Comment: It seems it's because you specified your matrix to be rank-deficient and also nothing mentioned of $X.$ It's easy to prove when $X$ has either full row rank or column rank, then your limit converges to left and right pseudo-inverses of $X$, respectively. When $X$ is deficient, sadly I think this blows up.

Comment: @dezdichado if we assume X is full row rank, could you explain how to show that the limit coverges to the left pseudo-inverse of X?  What changes in the argument in my previous comment?

Comment: I think in that case you use the SVD of $X$ and show that the limit converges to $X^+$ when written in terms of the SVD.

Comment: @WeakLearner Just wondering whether you've solved this. I can help if you haven't. :)

Comment: @SungheeYun It's been a while and I think I took a different approach, but it would definitely be nice to see a full solution if you can add one!

Comment: @WeakLearner So sorry that I haven't been responsive! I'll try my BEST to do it by this weekend. :( Job steals the time for the fun that I get by playing with this intriguing stuff! :)